# Javascript html element search and highlight

Tags: javascript, html, dom-traversal

I want to search a webpage for elements by tag name such a `<p>` or `<body>` or by class id and then highlight them. I want to do this using 3 buttons, set values, highlight next, and clear. Using three functions (getValues, highlightNext, clear)

1. First prompt the user to enter the value 1 or 2 corresponding to tag names or class names in the XHTML code.  The dialog must require a user to input a valid value (1 or 2), and the script should not allow the user to continue otherwise.
2. Next the script should prompt the user to enter a string corresponding to the tag name or class name they would like to highlight within the document.  This dialog must not allow a user to click cancel or enter the empty string as input.
3. When the user enters a proper value for the tag/class name, the function must retrieve the array of matching objects from the browser and tell the user how many elements matched their request with an alert box.
4. Each time highlightNext is called it will set the background color for the next matching element on the page to the same color.
5. Once all matching items have been highlighted, the function highlightNext should display a dialog box that indicates all elements have been highlighted.

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework.

Comment: What have you done so far and what is the problem you encountered?

Comment: @Jason: ["The homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812) but, Matt, please follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), including stating specific restrictions, what you've tried so far, and what specifically is confusing you.

Comment: I am only able to create a search function that can search a webpage for a letter, number or word and highlight it like a standard ctrl+f search feature in many browsers

Comment: What i cant figure out is how to implement a search that will search through the tag and class names and highlight them like i said above. I dont even know where to start

Comment: @roger did you read that whole answer? Maybe you missed this disclaimer: "This post is not the official position of the Stack Overflow administrators, but rather a community-edited effort to provide clear guidelines on how to respond to homework. Individual community members can of course use their own judgment." My personal judgement is to label it as homework so that people don't do someone's homework for them.

Comment: @Jason: Doesn't g.d.d.c's comment alert people to that, if the question didn't already?  How do you *know* this is Matt's homework?

Comment: @roger do i know 100%? no. but having been on this site for a while, you and i can pretty easily spot homework questions. new user, asking a question with bulleted, very specific requirements, and no apparent effort put into solving it him/herself. i would chalk that up to 98% certainty that it's homework. if it's not homework, matt should say so.

Comment: @Jason: What you describe sounds like a bad question regardless of whether it's homework or not.  Asking for more information, downvoting, and/or closing are how bad questions are dealt with, not tagging.  Notice I included two useful links for Matt to see how to ask better questions, both in my comment @directed at you, and in my edit reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedElements = document.getElementsByTagName(<tagname>)
```

will give you all DOM elements by specified tag name. (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp)
You can highlight them by applying a background color style, something like:

```
element.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
```

This should get you started.